# strophe.js - messages are not delivered on chrome

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'm creating custom xmpp chat application with use of Strophe.js. The communication between browser and desktop client (Adium) works perfectly. I can send messages via browser to Adium and from Adium to the browser. There is yet the problem with browser-browser communication at some point as messages are sent but not delivered. It seems it's just **Google Chrome** problem.

What's interesting is the fact that <presence> stanzas are sent and delivered fine. We use ejabberd as the server daemon.

This is the presence stanza I'm sending from one account:

```
<presence type="away" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <show>away</show>
    <status/>
</presence>
```

and what I receive on the other:

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="test1@domain.com/3917283126133167196759537" to="test2@domain.com/1563391996133167110798391" type="away">
    <show>away</show>
    <status/>
</presence>
```

also the message stanza I send:

```
<message from="test1@domain.com/267172122813316722921543" to="test2@domain.com" type="chat" id="4915" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates" />
    <body>Testing...</body>
</message>
```

and nothing is received on Chrome...

EDIT:
The problem was with escaping some characters. Chrome did not let them unescaped due to security issues.

Comment: Could you tell what is the problem with the characters. I am using strophe with punjab. I receive the just the first message, but not the later messages. Messages are sent but nothing is received on Chrome.

    <message type="chat" id="purple8a0d0124" to="receiver@gmail.com" from="sender@gmail.com/9806171F">
    <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
    <body>this is testing..</body>
    <nos:x value="disabled" xmlns:nos="google:nosave"/>
    <arc:record otr="false" xmlns:arc="http://jabber.org/protocol/archive"/>
    </message>

Comment: @NitishBorade are you sure nothing is received? It sounds like the listener function did not return `true` after the first message.

Answer (score 1):

The `type="away"` in your initial presence is not valid. Omit the 'type' attribute for available presence. Set `type="unavailable"` when you are going offline.

Because your presence is invalid you are not marked as available, and you will not receive any messages addressed to your bare JID.

**Update:** To clear any confusion about what I mean by the above (see comments)...

The 'type' attribute on this stanza is invalid:

```
<presence type="away" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <show>away</show>
    <status/>
</presence>
```

It is otherwise fine. There are two types of presence a client may send, available and unavailable. Standard available presence has no 'type' attribute. Unavailable presence has `type="unavailable"`. The actual status of the user (away, etc.) is signaled via the `<show/>` and `<status/>` elements, not the 'type' attribute.

To make it the above stanza a valid available presence, just remove `type="away"`:

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client">
    <show>away</show>
    <status/>
</presence>
```

Comment: Obviously, my initial presence stanza is active/available. Still, it doesn't make any difference as being "away" should not make it unable for the user to receive messages.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand me. Your initial presence is not valid - the 'type' attribute on the <presence> tag should not be there. The only valid 'type' a <presence> tag may have is "unavailable", otherwise it is an available presence. The rest of the stanza is fine. See http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-initial-gen for the spec.